# What is a generic element in a ring

Tags: commutative-algebra

I am now reading a commutative algebra paper, in which the name "generic element" of a commutative ring appears, however, I can not find the definition in that paper, and also my commutative algebra textbook.

So, could you please tell me what is a generic element in a commutative ring ? Where can I find its definition and related property ? What is it useful for ?

Thank for reading my question !

**Edit** That paper is a [survey on Castelnuovo-Mumford regularity](http://www.math.ac.vn/library/download/e-print/10/pdf/lthoa1001.pdf) and was written by Le Tuan Hoa. It firstly appear in the lemma 1.3.

Comment: Can you give some context? It may be just a sinonym for 'most elements' or 'all elements'.

Comment: Is there a topology on the ring?

Comment: Maybe a non-zero non-unit?

Comment: There seems to be a specialized meaning of *generic element* as described in this paper, [Integral Closure and Generic Elements](http://www.ndsu.edu/pubweb/~ciuperca/generic-final.pdf).  It appears that for ring $R$, a generic element is identified with a linear combination of generators $X_i$ for polynomial ring $R[X_1,..,X_n]$, i.e. a generic point in a multivariate extension of ring $R$.

Comment: What an unfortunate choice of terminology. Not as bad as defining a special meaning for "arbitrary element," but close!

Comment: I thought generic point always refers to elements of Spec(R). Have you thought about contacting the author?